# Android Firebase addValueEventListener excute later in loop

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is HomePage.java code

```
 ProfileDetail pd=new ProfileDetail(Email1);
                Log.d("TAG","profile in HomePage");
                Profile p=pd.getAllDetails();
                Log.d("TAG","profile after Method in HomePAge");
```

and this is my ProfileDetail class:

```
public class ProfileDetail implements Parcelable {


private  String mailId;
private Profile profile;
DatabaseReference  mDatabase= 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child("profile");
Profile pp=null;

protected ProfileDetail(Parcel in) {
    mailId = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ProfileDetail> CREATOR = new Creator<ProfileDetail>() {
    @Override
    public ProfileDetail createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ProfileDetail(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ProfileDetail[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ProfileDetail[size];
    }
};

public String getMailId() {
    return mailId;
}

public void setMailId(String mailId) {
    this.mailId = mailId;
}



public ProfileDetail(String mailId)
{
 Log.d("TAG","profile inside ProfileDetail mail= "+mailId);
 this.mailId=mailId;
    readData(new FireBaseCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(Profile p)
        {
            profile=p;
            Log.d("TAG","profile inside  louda pp="+p.toString());

            Log.d("TAG","profile inside  louda");
        }
    });
}

public Profile getAllDetails()
{

    Log.d("TAG","profile inside getALLDEtails");

    Log.d("TAG","profile inside  getALlDetails pp="+profile.toString());


return profile;
}

public void readData(final FireBaseCallBack fireBaseCallBack)
{
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Log.d("TAG","profile inside 1st datasnapshot");
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2:dataSnapshot1.getChildren())
            {
                if (mailId.equals(dataSnapshot2.getValue(String.class)))
                {
                    pp =dataSnapshot1.getValue(Profile.class);
                    Log.d("TAG","profile inside 2nd datasnapshot");
                    // p[0] =pp;
                }


            }


        }
        fireBaseCallBack.onCallback(pp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(mailId);
}


private interface FireBaseCallBack
{

    void onCallback(Profile p);
}
}
```

I am getting this result

profile in HomePage
profile inside getALLDEtails
profile going outside getALLDEtails
profile after Method in HomePAge
profile inside 1st datasnapshot
profile inside 1st datasnapshot
profile inside 1st datasnapshot
profile inside 2nd datasnapshot

I triend different  solution present here but nothing work By doing This I am always getting Profile object as null as Profile object is getting value later kindly help me on this

I

Comment: Yes, this is how it works.  Listeners are asynchronous and are invoked some time later, whenever the data becomes available.  You should design your code to account for this fact.

Comment: Can you help me to achieve my desired result

Comment: You didn't really say what your desired result it. I've already said everything you need to know - the API is asynchronous, and you need to work with it that way.  If you don't understand why Firebase APIs are asynchronous, read this blog: https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Comment: I got it about asynchronous .can you help me to  handle this i just need a profile data which is in firebase data base  so that i can get the role of my profile which i will use later in my code

Answer (score 0):

So, you just want to **read the value of the PROFILE field** from firebase database **only once**?

If that is the case, you have to set the listener for **a single value event** which is

```
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Write you logic here to extract the data 
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // ...
      }
});
```

Also, if you just want to get **limited child count**, you need to add

```
.limitToFirst(NUM_COUNT)
```

**e.g**

```
mDatabase.limitToFirst(2).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           // Write your logic here to extract the data
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // ...
          }
    });
```

Firebase Database is a real-time database, which means if you use **addValueEventListener()** it will keep updating the value every time the database value is changed.

**Note:** Make sure to remove the listener when you no longer need it.

Comment: Thanks rishabh  let me try this. Is addlistenerforSingleValue is not asynchronous

Comment: @bhaskar it should work, can you show the code which you changed?